# How to send an email when protractor e2e test case fails?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, protractor, e2e-testing

I am writing protractor e2e test cases. While running the test cases, if any test case fails it should send an email. How to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what are you using to run the tests? What is running karma? grunt? gulp?

Comment: he is probably running Protractor directly through: https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/bin/protractor

Comment: Jenkins is the right tool for CI and has email notifications built in, fully configurable. The other option is to look for a NodeJS  solution to send emails (Protractor runs in node).

Comment: But if the objective is to get notified locally when it fails; Growl notifications would be nice to have :)

Comment: @Davin Tryon, I am using webdriver for running test cases

Comment: @LeoGallucci do you think I've incorrectly explained the point in the answer? Trying to understand why somebody downvoted. Thanks.

Comment: Idk who downvoted your answer but my guess is because it doesn't strictly answer the question, he/she was probably looking a quick answer to how send emails from NodeJS on each failed jasmine spec and not interested in setting up Jenkins/Bamboo/x.

Comment: @LeoGallucci it makes sense, sometimes people are looking for copy/paste quick solutions and they don't want to hear a lecture about what are they doing wrong and what other things to have set up. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following Leo's comments.

This is not something you need to solve on the `protractor` level. `protractor` itself is basically a browser automation testing framework which mimics user action to test your web site.

The usual way to report about the test failures by email is to do it on a continuous integration server, like `jenkins` or `bamboo`. The idea is to use `JUnitXmlReporter` reporter from [`jasmine-reporters`](https://github.com/larrymyers/jasmine-reporters) to generate the `Junit XML` report which `jenkins` or `bamboo` know how to read and analyze. Then, report the test results by email.

Call `JUnitXmlReporter` in your `onprepare()` function in the [protractor config](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/spec/junitOutputConf.js):

```
onPrepare: function() {
    // The require statement must be down here, since jasmine-reporters
    // needs jasmine to be in the global and protractor does not guarantee
    // this until inside the onPrepare function.
    require('jasmine-reporters');
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(
      new jasmine.JUnitXmlReporter('xmloutput', true, true));
},
```